# FairPlay DRM support in iOS app for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer, fairplay

I have an video app, which requires me to use FairPlay DRM support. my question is If I use DRM service, will the generated URL (which is comprises of url+token) will be played by Avplayer (I made a custom AVPlayer).

Answer (score 1):

Not without the changes needed for fairplay drm.  You should review the sample application provided in the fairplay sdk to see what changes need to be made to your ios application to play the drm encrypted content.